# How to correctly configure ASP.NET Core 5 Swagger to work with Azure A/D authorization code authentication?

Tags: azure-active-directory, swagger, authorization, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-5.0

I am upgrading my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API security from implicit to authorization code. The authentication is done using Azure A/D and I also need to allow Swagger docs to be used.

I have managed to make it work, but client_secret is useless in my case and I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. My configuration is as follows:

#### Azure A/D

- Redirect URIs: https://localhost:44444/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html
- API permissions: Microsoft Graph + custom role (`access_as_user`)
- Tokens: Access tokens and ID tokens are unchecked

#### appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
},
```

#### Startup.cs

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);

private static void AddSwagger(IServiceCollection services, AzureAdAuthOptions auth)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Foo API", Version = "v1", });
        AddSwaggerDocs_IncludeXmlComments(c);

        c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{auth.Instance}/{auth.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri($"{auth.Instance}/{auth.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                    Scopes = { { $"api://{auth.ClientId}/access_as_user", "Access as user" } }
                }
            }
        });

        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "oauth2"
                    }
                },
                new string[] { }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

#### Swagger

- oauth2 (OAuth2, authorizationCode)
- Application: Foo - Swagger
- Authorization URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- Token URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token
- client_id: already filled in
- client_secret

Scopes: only one, `api://<guid>/access_as_user`

If I authorize without the secret, it works correctly. However, if I provide the secret I receive the following error:

> Auth ErrorError: Unauthorized, error: invalid_client, description:
> AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor
> 'client_secret' should be presented. Trace ID:
> dbb64172-2bbb-4392-8fc5-0ee71ab9c301 Correlation ID:
> 8c7edd8b-b6d0-435b-abeb-158b3278c3fe Timestamp: 2021-05-27 07:21:14Z

I thought the secret is required to make the authentication process more secure, but I do not seem to be able to use it. What am I doing wrong?

---

Double checked and `allowPublicClient` is false. I have switched from SPA to Web client, provided the secret, but I receive the following error:

> Auth ErrorError: Bad Request, error: invalid_request, description:
> AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the
> 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Trace ID:
> 6e11093f-319b-4d75-92b9-c6a39775a501 Correlation ID:
> afcd9152-ccd5-4588-ae75-0b829272d66d Timestamp: 2021-05-28 06:10:58Z

So, it seems that I am stuck with the SPA client when using Swagger UI.

Comment: Did you choose the `web` when you created the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that your application is a public client application and not a confidential client application.  Please see [the differences between public client and confidential client applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-applications).

To solve this problem, you only need to modify the application manifest, change `allowPublicClient` to `false`.

[image]

Also, make sure you select **Web** when creating the application.

[image]

Comment: Yes, since the authentication seems to be performed by the Swagger UI (using jQuery in the browser) I think I must remain with SPA and the public. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction (the differences between public client and confidential client applications).

Comment: FYI the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0  "suggests" to use the URL using port 5001,  this is correct.  Also, it doesn't say which kind of application to authorize and if it's the official visual studio wizard-generated SPA it should be WEB, not SPA!  

Comment: I was not able to pass the authentication process. The error is `Auth ErrorError: Bad Request, error: invalid_request, description: AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. `. So what can I do?