# Configure Authorization Code with PKCE Flow on SwaggerUI for AzureAD Authentication/Authorization

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to authorize using Authorization Code grant flow for AzureAD from SwaggerUI for my .net core based API project but I am getting below error,

**Error: Unauthorized, error: invalid_client, description: AADSTS700025: Client is public so neither 'client_assertion' nor 'client_secret' should be presented.**

Though my Client is not public, even I verified app-manifest, it has "allowPublicClient": false.

**Setup Over AzureAD**

1. HostAPP
2. ClientAPP

HostAPP has scopes exposed and same are added to ClientAPP under App Permissions.

ClientAPP has redirect-uri of swagger added under SPA as I am using authorization code grant type.

**Note:** Without supplying secret, I am able to authenticate but I want to make secret mandatory.

Same is reported by other user in question posted below but the answer is not clear yet even though it has accepted answer.

[How to correctly configure ASP.NET Core 5 Swagger to work with Azure A/D authorization code authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717463/how-to-correctly-configure-asp-net-core-5-swagger-to-work-with-azure-a-d-authori)

**Edit:**

I have Swagger redirect URL added in SPA and Postman redirect URL in Web.

[image]

Comment: Could you please include the [option](https://i.imgur.com/CcmZz4p.png) you selected while registering apps(Web/SPA)?

Comment: As mentioned, I have added Swagger Redirect url in SPA and Postman Callback url in Web.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I registered application in Azure AD and added **`redirect URI`** under SPA:

[image]

**When I tried to generate the access token, I got the same error like below:**

[image]

**To resolve the error, I added the redirect URI under Web by deleting the SPA  and Save like below:**

[image]

**After modifying the changes, get the authorization code again and generate the access token like below:**

[image]

So, try deleting the *Swagger Redirect URL* in **SPA** and add it under **Web** to get access token successfully as suggested in this **[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717463/how-to-correctly-configure-asp-net-core-5-swagger-to-work-with-azure-a-d-authori)** by ***Carl Zhao***.

Comment: Moved Swagger redirect URL to Web and see this error =>

"auth errorError: Bad Request, error: invalid_request, description: AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Trace ID: 091c349b-01f2-49c8-a023-ae14ce168300 Correlation ID: 7e69deeb-5f9d-4c23-80f2-a8bc5b34d52f Timestamp: 2022-06-21 13:30:45Z"

Comment: In My case, able to generate token from Postman. From swaggerUI the question is posted. It would be helpful if you can try to configure AzureAD Auth Code flow for SwaggerUI.

Comment: Please check whether `replyUrlsWithType` in [**Manifest**](https://i.imgur.com/UtlhRMS.png) is updated to **Web** or not. Check this [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-oauth-2-authorization-using-azure-ad-and-swagger-in-net-5-0/) that includes Enabling OAuth 2 Authorization Using Azure AD And Swagger In .NET 5.0

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I see that Manifest has been updated but still same error. The blog you shared is depicting implicit flow and I tried it, I am able to generate the token but the issue I am facing is for Auth Code flow. Can you please help on the same.

Comment: Just wanted to add it, that If I use Swagger redirect URL in SPA and if I try to authorize on swagger without providing secret then it is working. Shouldn't we pass secret while authenticating?

Comment: For **SPA**, you don't need to provide secret, and it won't work if you add. For Web apps, client secret is mandatory while using auth code flow.

Comment: You can check this **[MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code)** that includes the parameters supported by SPA using auth code flow. It does n't support client_secret as a parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245818/discussion-between-sridevimachavarapu-mt-and-pinkesh-patel).