OAuth 2.0 authentication with Swagger UI
I have an ASP.NET Core Web Api project with following program.cs file:
    using (var scope = temporaryProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var dataverseUtilityService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataverseUtilityService>();

            // Fetch tenantId and clientId from DataverseUtilityService
            var configuration = dataverseUtilityService.GetConfiguration();
            var tenantId = configuration.msys_AzureTenantId;
            var clientId = configuration.msys_AzureClientId;

            // Swagger configuration with OAuth2 using Authorization Code Flow and client secret
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });

                // Define OAuth2 Authorization Code Flow (without PKCE)
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Description = "OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow (with client secret)",
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                            TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal)
                            {
                                { $"api://{clientId}/access_the_api/.default", "Access API" },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                });

                options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "oauth2",
                            },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "oauth2",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        },
                        new List<string> { $"api://{clientId}/access_the_api/.default" }
                    },
                });
            });
        }

        // Build the app after adding Swagger configuration
        var app = builder.Build();

        // Enable Swagger UI and Swagger endpoint in all environments
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MedlemssystemApi V1");
            c.OAuth2RedirectUrl(url: "https://app-dev-medlemssystemapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html");
        });

        // Basic middleware for all environments
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        // Map controllers and APIs
        app.MapControllers();

        // Run the app
        app.Run();

And I have setup my App Registration authentication as follows:


and manually setup of following scope:

The issue occurs when I try to authenticate in Swagger UI:

following error occurs:
auth errorError: response status is 400, error: invalid_request, description: AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Request origin: 'https://app-dev-medlemssystemapi.azurewebsites.net'. Trace ID: eeb5797b-7c22-4162-a2f9-ae086eef1300 Correlation ID: 5a6cbca2-73c5-4ad8-8352-58d80ad6d47f Timestamp: 2024-09-19 14:41:59Z

It seems like it always expect the redirect url to be configured as Single Page Application?. Is it possible to get the authentication flow to work with Web App configuration instead ?.

Check this https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/oauth2.md

Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717463/how-to-correctly-configure-asp-net-core-5-swagger-to-work-with-azure-a-d-authori  authentication performed by the Swagger UI it must remain with SPA and the public.

OR useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant: true,     usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant: true set it as false

Would you like to take a look at my test before? My test referred to this blog, which might require you to change AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow to Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow() and modify settings in app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>.

@TinyWang am I forced to use Implicit flow here ?. I do not want save/fetch the client secret in the application code. Isn't it possible to get it to work using AuthorizationFlow rather than implicit flow ?

AuthorizationFlow also requires client secret to generate the access token. I'm not sure whether we could use auth code flow here. In another case I handled before, I might test with auth code flow, but I forgot whether it worked or not.

I find that case, and yes, I test to use AuthorizationCode as the flow but it doesn't work for me.

@Osman Esen Are expecting this as an output.

I created a sample Swagger UI Authorization for ASP .NET Core API, and it was successfully authorized without any errors.

It seems like it always expect the redirect url to be configured as Single Page Application?

Yes, you are correct. The only way is to configure redirect URI in Single Page Application platform. If you use Web platform, it will throw same error.

To avoid the error, I placed the Authorization URL, Token and Scope in appsettings.json. instead of in program.cs.

I used the below scope,

"Scope": "api://<API-appregistration-client-id/access_as_user",

appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "microsoft.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "<tenant-id>",
    "ClientId": "<client-id",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scope": "access_as_user"
  },
  "SwaggerAAD": {
    "AuthorizationUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "TokenUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "Scope": "api://<API-appregistration-client-id/access_as_user",
    "ClientId": "<client-id>"
  }
}

Below is code for Swagger UI Authentication.
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    o => {
        o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Swagger Azure Ad", Version = "v1" });
        o.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "oauth2.0",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:TokenUrl"]),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"],"Access API as User" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference=new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,Id="oauth2"}
                },
                new []{builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"]}
            }
        });
    });
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        o =>
        {
            o.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:ClientId"]);
            o.OAuthUsePkce();
            o.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        });
}

My complete program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    o => {
        o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "Swagger Azure Ad", Version = "v1" });
        o.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Name = "oauth2.0",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:AuthorizationUrl"]),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:TokenUrl"]),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"],"Access API as User" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        o.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference=new OpenApiReference{Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,Id="oauth2"}
                },
                new []{builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:Scope"]}
            }
        });
    });
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        o =>
        {
            o.OAuthClientId(builder.Configuration["SwaggerAAD:ClientId"]);
            o.OAuthUsePkce();
            o.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
        });
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();


The redirect URL for the Azure AD API App Registration is set in the web application as shown below.



For the SwaggerAAD App Registration, I set the Redirect URL to the Single-page application as shown below.



Make sure to grant admin consent for your API.


Here's successful authorization without any errors.



